# Weighted graph traversal with skips

Tags: algorithm, weighted, graph-traversal

While I was in the shower today, I had a thought - How difficult would it be to write an algorithm to traverse a weighted di-graph and find the shortest path while allowed to skip a fixed number of edges s. I started thinking about even one skip, and for the brute force method it seems to multiply the problem by the number of edges in your graph, as you have to find the shortest path for each case where an edge is set to 0 cost and then compare across all graphs. I don't know if there are any algorithms that do this, but a cursory search of google didn't show any.

My first question would be for skipping the most costed edge(s), but it's also an interesting problem to examine having to find a path assuming you skip the least costed edge(s).

This is just to satisfy my curiosity, so no rush.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What follows is the logic of how to solve this problem.  The way to solve this type of problem is to consider a graph composed of two copies of the original graph you want to traverse, which I'll describe how to create.  For your sake, draw a small graph, and then draw it topologically sorted (which helps with the visualization, but is not necessary in the program.)  Next, draw a copy of that graph a few inches above the original.  You're in the bottom section of this graph when you have not yet used your skip, and you're in the top part when you have used your skip.  Let's call the nodes in the bottom graph A1, A2, A3 ... and the nodes in the top graph B1, B2, B3 ...  If, in your original graph, node 1 is connected to nodes 2, then your new graph has edges A1->A2, B1->B2, and a free connection, A1->B2 (with edge cost 0).

Consider the following original graph, where you start at the black node, and desire to end up at the blue node.

[image]

Your new graph will look like the following, where you again start at black and wish to go to the blue node.

[image]

At each location in the bottom half of the graph, you have not used your skip, and thus can either skip (moving to the top part of the graph) or can move normally, going to another node in the bottom graph.

You can then use any of the standard graph traversal algorithms.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. And in order to implement more skips you just add more copies of the graph - an elegant solution. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure how it would function for the case of skipping least costed edges but I'll try thinking like this and see if I can come up with a solution.

Comment: Since this helped,  would you mind accepting the answer?   There should be a check mark next to it that you can press.